# Can not connect to the azure-sql-edge. Why?

Tags: sql-server, docker, containers, connection-string, azure-sql-edge

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    # Database instance
    mssql:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:latest
      volumes:
        - events_mssql:/var/opt/mssql
      ports:
        - 1433:1433
      environment:
        - ACCEPT_EULA=1
        - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Passw@rd

volumes:
    events_mssql:
```

`setup.sql`:

```
CREATE DATABASE $(MSSQL_DB);
CREATE DATABASE $(MSSQL_DB_AUDIT_LOG);
GO
USE $(MSSQL_DB);
GO
CREATE LOGIN $(MSSQL_USER) WITH PASSWORD = '$(MSSQL_PASSWORD)';
GO
CREATE USER $(MSSQL_USER) FOR LOGIN $(MSSQL_USER);
GO
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [$(MSSQL_USER)];
GO
```

[image]

Here is the running container:

[image]

I am trying to connect to the database through the [Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-mssql.mssql):

Using this connection string: `Server=http://localhost:1433/;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=Passw@rd;`

I am getting the error:

> mssql: Error: Unable to connect using the connection information provided. Retry profile creation?

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: SQL server doesn’t use http.  Check your connection string.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, the `Server=localhost:1433;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=Passw@rd;` connection string does not work either. The same error is shown.

Comment: If you're using [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) or later also try adding `TrustServerCertificate=yes;` to your connection string after removing http.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, the `Server=localhost:1433;TrustServerCertificate=yes;Database=events_service;User Id=SA;Password=Passw@rd;` connection string does not work as well. :(

Comment: Also try `Server=tcp:127.0.0.1,1433;` with a comma `,` before the port number instead of a colon `:`. Depending on your network configuration and default protocols `localhost` could resolve to either `127.0.0.1` (IPv4) or `::1` (IPv6), but Docker is only listening on IPv4 ports by default.

Comment: Also, have you checked the container's log output for errors (by clicking on it in the Docker Desktop GUI)? The container may be considered up by Docker, but the SQL Server service inside it may not be listening or accepting connections for various reasons.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, the `Server=tcp:127.0.0.1,1433;Database=master;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User=sa;Password=Passw@rd;` worked just fine. Thank you. 

Comment: at volumes you have some value at events_mssql or it is empty?